# Cannot merge using ClearCase Remote Client (CCRC)

Tags: merge, clearcase-remote-client

Linux - Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.4 (Santiago)
Rational ClearCase Remote Client, Version: 7.1.2, Build id: 7.1.2.D100920

I am trying to merge from a subbranch back up to a higher (parent) branch using CCRC and the Version Tree screen.  When I select the version to merge and right-click, the "Merge To View Selected Version..." option is disabled (grayed out).  If I perform this same operation at the server (using Windows Clearcase Explorer), it works fine - same domain, same user, same password (or same account) and same config spec.

Is there some permission that may be turned off with the CCRC to disallow graphical merges?  I suspect I am doing something wrong, because I do not find any other complaints about this.

Thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CCRC is able [to diff and merge](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/cchelp/v7r0m1/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.rational.clearcase.doc/topics/t_ccteam_diffmerge.htm) through the version tree.

But if the merge isn't directly available, I would first:

- checkout the destination version (the one onto which you want to merge)
- try and merge from the source version to the checked-out one.

7.1.2 should have the fixes mentioned in earlier CCRC merge bug (like [this one](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg1PK86184)).

The option, even available, can still have a [bug in 7.1.2](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448521), when an external tool is configured in the CCRC settings, but not available on the computer: see [this technote](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21448521).

> From `Window > Preferences`, navigate to `Team > ClearCase Remote Client > Integration > Compare/Merge` and choose "`ClearCase External`" as the default tool for comparing and merging files.
>   In the version tree, right-click on a file and choose "`Merge to View Selected Version.`" The file will be checked out, but no merge will happen, and no error will display.

---

The [OP Herb Miller](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2463702/herb-miller) adds [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16985985/cannot-merge-using-clearcase-remote-client-ccrc/16986532?noredirect=1#comment24541108_16986532):

> I have been told that a snapshot view can only see an element in a view from one branch, and that is why I cannot checkout the destination element in CCRC. In the ClearCase Explorer, the views just happen to be dynamic.

The issue is related to snapshot or dynamic view, but *also* related to how a merge works:

You can merge *from* any version (even in a CCRC web - snapshot-like - view).
But you can only merge *to* a version:

- selected by your current view
- able to be checked out by your current view.

In other words, the important part of a merge from the version tree isn't the source version (on which you will right-click and select "`Merge To View Selected Version...`", but the *destination* version.

If you right-click (in order to trigger a merge to another version) on a version currently selected by your snapshot view, I am not surprise that the merge option is grayed: a snapshot view can only check out a version visible and selected, that source version is the only "destination" for that merge: you wouldn't be able to merge that version on itself.

Comment: Even using "ClearCase External", the option is still grayed out.  I do not understand it, but I cannot checkout the destination version in CCRC, but I can check it out with ClearCase Explorer.

Comment: @HerbMiller check if the config spec of your CCRC web view is the same as the one you are using with a full (dynamic or snapshot) ClearCase view.

Comment: Yes, config specs are the same.  I may be running up against the difference in a snapshot view versus a dynamic view.  I have been told that a snapshot view can only see an element in a view from one branch, and that is why I cannot checkout the destination element in CCRC.  In the ClearCase Explorer, the views just happen to be dynamic.  Does that make sense?

Comment: @HerbMiller yes, it does make sense, and I have edited the answer to address that case.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the correct direction.  I tried the following and it worked, although there may be a better way.

Comment: On my CCRC I now have 2 snapshot views.  One view points to my personal branch.  The other view points to the branch I want to merge to.  I make changes and check them in on my personal branch in one view.  Then I can merge the changes up using the other view.  I am new to stackoverflow.  I will try to mark this question as answered.

Comment: @HerbMiller sounds great. If you are new to Stack Overflow, don't forget to read http://stackoverflow.com/about, and http://stackoverflow.com/help.